# How do I get a marketo form embed to work on my page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, embed, marketo

I have a landing page created outside Marketo and I've been asked to embed a form script. It's not showing up.

I tested the lightbox version- this one does work.
I tested other scripts and they don't work. 
I tested on a simple html page and it doesn't show up. (I thought maybe because I have other scripts running.)

I do not have access to their Marketo account. Is there something they can do to allow me to embed this on my host server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have your client right click the form they want to embed, click 'Embed Code', select the code type as normal, then copy the script Marketo provides.

Answer (score 0):

See these instructions:
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/

You can ask the customer to follow these steps to re-generate the HTML embed code and then try to implement it again.

If you're still having troubles please send a link to this page.